# How to make disqus load avatar picture instead of user picture?

Tags: users, comments

In user profiles I created a field called **Avatar** with a machine name of `field_avatar`.

I was wondering if I could make Disqus load the Avatar picture instead of the default Drupal user picture.

Here is the default Disqus code

```
        // Load the user's avatar.
    $user_picture_default = variable_get('user_picture_default', '');
    if (isset($account->picture) && !empty($account->picture) && is_numeric($account->picture) && $file = file_load($account->picture)) {
      $data['avatar'] = !empty($file->uri) ? $file->uri : NULL;
    }
    elseif (!empty($user_picture_default)) {
      $data['avatar'] = variable_get('user_picture_default', '');
    }
    if (isset($data['avatar'])) {
      $data['avatar'] = file_create_url($data['avatar']);
    }
  }
  drupal_alter('disqus_user_data', $data);

  return $data;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As seen in above code you can use **disqus_user_data_alter** hook to change disqus data in your custom module...

```
function YOURMODULENAME_disqus_user_data_alter(&$data) {
  global $user;
  $user_picture_default = variable_get('user_picture_default', '');
if (!empty($user->field_profile_picture[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['fid'])) {
  // Load the file -- Change field_profile_picture with your field name
  $file = file_load($user->field_profile_picture[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['fid']);

  // Note the style name is "profile_picture" as explained in your question,
  // not "profile_pic" which was in your original code
    $data['avatar'] = !empty($file->uri) ? $file->uri : NULL;
  }
  elseif (!empty($user_picture_default)) {
    $data['avatar'] = variable_get('user_picture_default', '');
  }
  if (isset($data['avatar'])) {
      $data['avatar'] = file_create_url($data['avatar']);
  }
}
```

Comment: I replaced field_profile_picture with field_avatar and YOURMODULENAME with disquspatch, which is what I named my module. It didn't work, for some reason it just displays my logo image and not my avatar.

Comment: to clarify, it just displays the default picture for the user picture, and not my avatar.